# C++ Client to a Java Server(TCP/IP)

Tags: java, c++, sockets, tcp, ip

To start off, i'm very new to networking with sockects and TCP/IP packets, i would appreciate it if you could explain in a very clear manner. My robotics program is attempting to use a kinect with our current robot for the first time, but we have a problem. Currently they code in java, while they plan on coding the kinect in C++. Is it possible to use TCP/IP packets to send information between the two languages? We need a C++ Client and a Java server. If anyone has links or examples i would really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Of course, TCP/IP is agnostic to the language. But if both the Java and C++ part are running on the same machine, you may consider using the [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) to create the Kinect interface in C++ and have Java consume it via JNI.

Comment: If you are networking though, you don't need JNI since you will be communcating through Sockets.

Comment: The socket example for java is universal and trivial. What is your target for C++? Windows? LINUX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problems communicating between Java and C/C++ is the byte ordering problem. If you are going to be sending binary data, you must design the communications structures clearly and completely, including number sizes (in bytes), bit-order (lsb/msb, swapped-byte or non-swapped bytes in short, ints, and longs), and structure packing (the number of pad bytes between fields in a structure).

I recommend that you don't communicate in binary if you can avoid it. For two reasons;

1. No worrying about bit-order, byte swapping, and structure packing.
2. Eavesdrop on the communications without decoding the data. You still have ascii/unicode issues here.

**EDIT**
In C/C++, data is stored in a way that makes CPU access fast and easy. The fields of a class/structure are aligned on word boundaries (because most CPUs can only access memory in full word chunks), and the bits are ordered to match the CPU. But, CPU's can have different bit orders and word sizes (16, 32, 64, ...). Most Intel CPU's are little endian, and most other designs are big endian. To make life more interesting, the java virtual machine is big endian on every platform. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

So, if you want two C/C++ machines to be able to communicate, then you must send the data in a way that both can read it. Normally, to communicate in a heterogenous environment (called 'over the wire') you specify that all communications are done in a particular format. TCP/IP uses MSB (most significant bit) ordering. All the programs then have to translate (if necessary) from the wire format.

Because CPUs consume memory in word length chunks, then the compilers put pad bytes between fields that don't fill a whole machine word. For a machine that reads 32 bit words, a structure like this:

```
struct example1 {
  char someFlag;
  int  someCount;
};
```

would actually take 8 bytes of memory. The first field consists of a single byte of data and 3 pad bytes, so that the integer references are aligned on word boundaries. If a naive communicator tries to send the data in this structure, say `send(&example1, sizeof(example1));` to another system with a different word size or byte ordering, where the other system does `read(&example1, sizeof(example1));`, then the value of example1.someCount may be very different than expected.

Most of this is normally academic until you throw Java into it. Because Java is always MSB format. So sending from a C/C++ application to a Java application, even on the same hardware, may cause this same unexpected result.

Java contains my favorite I/O class, `java.nio.ByteBuffer`. It has the ability to read ints, longs, floats, and doubles from practically any source. If you know how the data was created, this will read it. ByteBuffer has `getShort`, `getInt`, etc. methods to get any type, as well as an `order()` method to set the byte order of the data.

Comment: I really appreciate the help guys, just to expand on your answer a little more @Zagrev:  if I'm sending data from the kinect over to the robot(java), wouldn't i need to send it using binary data? if not, how   would i send the information?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want two programs to talk to each other over a network you need to define a [protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_protocol).

A protocol defined on top of TCP needs to specify a way to tell the receiver when the entire message has been received. Two common ways to do this are:

- Specifying some special sequence of data that signals the "end". An example is HTTP which makes use of a special CRLF character to signal the end of the non-payload part of the message.
- Specifying the length of the message in some predefined part of the message. An example is HTTP which specifies the length of the payload in a "Content-Length" header.

You can find more info on HTTP message structure here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html

Further you would probably like a platform agnostic format for encoding the payload. A good binary format is Google's Protocol Buffer which is supported very well in Java and C++: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can exchange information between programs implemented different languages. (Did you expect that whole Internet uses Java?)

Here is something I found after Googling "socket programming {Java, C++}":

http://codebase.eu/tutorial/linux-socket-programming-c/ - seems to be OK

http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-1996/jw-12-sockets.html - Java tutorial

But be careful. Depending on your hardware architecture you might get into some problems when exchanging binary data (byte ordering etc.). As you are using object oriented languages you can consider using some kind of middleware which handles low level communication - e.g. [Ice](http://www.zeroc.com/ice.html). However, this might be an overkill in your case.